# Using tinyreq/cheerio is there a way to bypass the certificate chain on a site?

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying scrape a site and I'm using both npm modules tinyreq/cheerio as noted on [this blog post](https://www.codementor.io/johnnyb/how-to-write-a-web-scraper-in-nodejs-du108266t)

The site I am trying to scrape uses TLS I run into the following error below:

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38) code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
```

Is there a way I can bypass this in node? Or would I have to include the actual cert within the script?